# Paypal missing from backend

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, magento-ce

In my site, paypal is missing from the admin side.It is working perfectly on fronted. But not showing in payment methods.Now I want to change paypal account credentials. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you update? In 1.8+ Paypal is in payment methods instead of his own menu

Comment: I have 1.7.0.2 And it is not in the payment methods.I checked it.

Comment: Then check wether it is activated in `/app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml` or maybe deactivated in another xml.

Comment: I have checked from the admin backend.and paypal module is enabled from admin backend. So is it still possible that it may be disabled?

Comment: Yes. The admin backend checks for the existance of the node and ignores the status

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: I checked Mage_All.xml and it is activated.

Comment: Check if the `system.xml` file of the Paypal module exists.

Comment: @Marius:I checked this file also.It does exist.