# paypal checkout issue magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, paypal

i want to know that is magento 1.9 not support paypal standard?

Below is the screenshot of magento 1.9, as in backend it is not visible 
[image]

while in magento 1.8, paypal methods are visible [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 1.9 support paypal standard.**

May be you can check `app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml`. find `Mage_Paypal`. Verify this module should be enable.

[image]

Comment: yes, Mage_Paypal is enabled

Comment: May be there is some error. Or some third party extension overriding paypal. Try disable local modules from `app/etc/local.xml`

Comment: not worked still....

Comment: What is your base currency? Change it to US dollar. then check and let me know

Comment: its US dollar sir.. basically the above screenshots that i shared with you, are my websites when i use magento 1.8 it works fine but when i upgrade its version it shows error in whole site so i change domain and switch my site to new domain and now in this domain i again facing paypal methods problem

Comment: Check comments here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15191/paypal-missing-from-backend. May be useful for you

Comment: i follow steps that recommended in the link provided by you, but no success :(

Comment: It seems you PayPal express checkout button is appear on http://www.hotdeals4less.com/checkout/cart/, is `Compilation`  enabled? If so then try to recompile it.

Comment: hello jayesh, can you suggest me from where i recompile it? as i don't know much about it so if possible then please guide me ,, thanks :)

Comment: First ensure your compilation is enable, navigate to **`Magento Admin > System > Tools > Compilation`** on that page verify **`Compiler Status`**. If its **`Enabled`** then click on **`Run Compilation Process`** button which is locate on same page. You dont need to recompile if its status is **`Disabled`**.

Comment: yes its status is already disabled

Comment: is there anyone who provide solution of my issue???